# Access Denied VIMConfigurations.XML

Tags: python

I'm on 64 bits Windows 8 Sony VAIO computer. I'm trying to build a Distribution file but error in access denied appears everywhere. Solving initially Administration privileges, i stuck at this error.

```
Access Denied : Local Configuration\\Sony Corporation\\VAIO or Control Center\\VIMConfigurations.XML
```

I tried to find this file without results. Finally i uninstall VAIO Control Center. The message is still the same.

**nester.py**

```
def print_lol(the_list):

>Esta función me permite crear un array de cadenas

    for each_item in the_list:
        if isinstance(each_item,list):
            print_lol(each_item)
        else:
            print(each_item)
```

**setup.py**

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    name        = 'nester',
    version     = '1.0.0',
    py_modules  = ['nester'],
    author      = 'cleon',
    author_email    = 'calobeto.leon@gmail.com',
    url         = 'http://',
    description = ' A simple printer of nested files',
    )
```

I need your help. Thanks.

Comment: Is the file in use ? Is it controlled by a windows service that you need to stop first ?

Comment: It's not a windows service.